# Wildcard Array in If Statement in VBA Part 2

Tags: excel, vba

So I asked this question last week and I kind of have a solution to this question, but there is just one piece that is not working. The Application.Match part does not seem to work. I am also getting results when myarray does not match with arr(1).

The original question was :

What I am trying to do with this code is to :

1. Go through all the files in that specified folder and all the subfolders in that folder. (The files in that folder are usually separated in 5 parts by underscore. For example, "XX1_XX2_XX3_XX4_XX5"
2. If any of the 3 character indicators in my myarray matches XX2 from the filename, then list XX4 on Cell(22,3) and XX5 on Cell(22,4) and keep repeating ......Cell(23,3),Cell(23,4),Cell(24,3,),Cell(24,4).....etc. I want only exact matches.. not sure how to do that.
3. There are some files in the folder that has only 3 underscores... so "XX1_XX2_XX3_XX4". For these files, if myarray matches XX2, then list XX4 on Cells(i,3) and show "NO INDICATOR" for Cells(i,4)

```
Sub tracker()

    Const FPATH As String = "\\KEVINXX\FILESXX\FILES\"
    Dim f As String, i, j As Long, arr, sht As Worksheet
    Dim myarray As Variant
    myarray = Array("XXX", "AAA", "BBB", "SBM", "SBS", "JDS", "QQQ", "WWW", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "XXX", "AAS", "RRR", "SSS", "KKK", "ABX")
    Set sht = ActiveSheet



    f = Dir("\\KEVINXX\FILESXX\FILES\")
    i = 22
    Do While f <> ""

        'split filename on underscore
        arr = Split(f, "_", 5)

        If UBound(arr) >= 3 Then
            If IsError(Application.Match(arr(1), myarray, 0)) Then
                If UBound(arr) = 3 Then
                    sht.Cells(i, 3).Value = Left(arr(3), Len(arr(3)) - 5)
                    sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = "No Indicator"
                Else
                    sht.Cells(i, 3).Value = arr(3)
                    If UBound(arr) >= 4 Then
                        sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = Left(arr(4), Len(arr(4)) - 5)

                    End If
                End If
                i = i + 1
            End If 'no match
        End If
        f = Dir() 'next file
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of asking a new question why not ask the provider of the answer about the issue?

Comment: I also notice you have a habit of no feedback.  Without feedback we do not know if what we did helped or hindered.  One should mark those answers that are used as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  If answers did not work please inform the author through comments about the errors and what is not working, they are the best to help overcome problems with the code they provided.  Without feedback people will stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looping through the array

```
for x = 0 to 16
    If IsError(Application.Match(arr(1), myarray(x), 0)) Then
        If UBound(arr) = 3 Then
            sht.Cells(i, 3).Value = Left(arr(3), Len(arr(3)) - 5)
            sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = "No Indicator"
        Else
            sht.Cells(i, 3).Value = arr(3)
            If UBound(arr) >= 4 Then
                sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = Left(arr(4), Len(arr(4)) - 5)

            End If
        End If
            i = i + 1
    End If 'no match
next x
```

Be kind and rewind or leave feedback)